# Action is dispatched, but state is not updating

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am new to redux, and I have read the other questions concerning this topic. I have tried and looked for quite sometime at this point. I am using redux dev tools in and chrome, and can see my action pulling in the information I need, but it is not going to the state. Here is some of my code, any help would be greatly appreciated.

actions.js

```
export const FETCH_DATA = {
  FETCH_DATA_BEGIN: "FETCH_DATA_BEGIN",
  FETCH_DATA_SUCCESS: "FETCH_DATA_SUCCESS",
  FETCH_DATA_FAILURE: "FETCH_DATA_FAILURE",
};

export const fetchDataBegin = () => ({
  type: FETCH_DATA.FETCH_DATA_BEGIN,
});

export const fetchDataSuccess = (data) => ({
  type: FETCH_DATA.FETCH_DATA_SUCCESS,
  payload: data,
});
```

Reducers.js

```
import { FETCH_DATA } from "./actions";

const initialState = {
  data: [],
  loading: false,
  error: null,
};

export default function displayDataReducer(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case FETCH_DATA.FETCH_DATA_BEGIN:
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: true,
        error: null,
      };
    //Sets the data
    case FETCH_DATA.FETCH_DATA_SUCCESS:
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: false,
        data: action.payload.data,
      };
```

my store/index.js

```
import { createStore, combineReducers, applyMiddleware, compose } from "redux";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";

import displayDataReducer from "./displayData/reducer";

// The Dev Tool extension for the browser
const composeEnhancers = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose;

// export const RootReducer = combineReducers({
//   data: displayDataReducer,
// });

export default createStore(
  displayDataReducer,
  composeEnhancers(applyMiddleware(thunk))
);
```

my component

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import axios from "axios";

import Navbar from "../brand/Navbar";
import Masthead from "../brand/Masthead";
import Footer from "../brand/Footer";
import MainContent from "../content/MainContent";

function App() {
  const content = useSelector((state) => state);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  function getData() {
    return (dispatch) => {
      axios.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1").then((res) =>
        dispatch({
          type: "FETCH_DATA.FETCH_DATA_SUCCESS",
          data: res.data,
        })
      );
    };
  }
  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getData());
  }, []);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Issue:** `type: "FETCH_DATA.FETCH_DATA_SUCCESS"` should just be `type: "FETCH_DATA_SUCCESS"`, or perhaps you didn't mean to include the quotes around it, in which case you also need to import `FETCH_DATA`.

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import axios from "axios";

import Navbar from "../brand/Navbar";
import Masthead from "../brand/Masthead";
import Footer from "../brand/Footer";
import MainContent from "../content/MainContent";

function App() {
  const content = useSelector((state) => state);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  function getData() {
    return (dispatch) => {
      axios.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1").then((res) =>
        dispatch({
          type: "FETCH_DATA_SUCCESS", // <-- Drop the prefix
          data: res.data,
        })
      );
    };
  }
```

OR

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import axios from "axios";

import { FETCH_DATA } from "./actions"; // <-- import actions

import Navbar from "../brand/Navbar";
import Masthead from "../brand/Masthead";
import Footer from "../brand/Footer";
import MainContent from "../content/MainContent";

function App() {
  const content = useSelector((state) => state);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  function getData() {
    return (dispatch) => {
      axios.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1").then((res) =>
        dispatch({
          type: FETCH_DATA.FETCH_DATA_SUCCESS,
          data: res.data,
        })
      );
    };
  }
```